# Find the following expectation: $E\Big[g\big(f(x)-c\big)\Big]$

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, uniform-distribution

I want to find the expectation of the following function:
$$ E\Big[g\big(f(x)-c\big)\Big] \tag{1}$$
where $c$ is a constant.

1. First consider the case when $g(y)=-e^{-y}$, $f(x)=ax^b\; (a,b>0)$, and $x\sim U(i,j) \;(j>i>0)$. Is it possible to find explicitly the above expectation?
2. Is it possible to find the expectation term for an arbitrary function $f$, while function $g$ and random variable $x$ are as specified in 1? If it is then how? If not, then under what conditions would this be feasible?

With respect to 1, I was trying to write $(1)$ as $E[-e^{-{(ax^b-c)}}]$ but now I am unsure how to proceed. If we take a function $h(x)=-e^{-(ax^b-c)}$,  would $E[h(x)]=h(E[x])$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ X\sim U(i,j)\ $, then for any (sufficiently regular) function $\ h\ $
$$
E[h(x)]=\frac{\displaystyle\int_i^jh(y)dy}{j-i}\ .
$$
In particular, if $\ h(x)={-}e^{-(ax^b-c)}\ $, then
\begin{align}
E\big[{-}e^{-(ax^b-c)}\big]&=\frac{\displaystyle\int_i^j{-}e^{-(ay^b-c)}dy}{j-i}\\
&=\frac{{-}e^c}{j-i}\int_i^je^{-ay^b}dy\ .
\end{align}
The integral can be evaluated in terms of *elementary functions* if $\ b=1\ $, but not, as far as I know, for any other value of $\ b\ $.  If $\ b=2\ $, it can be evaluated in terms of [Gauss's error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), erf.  Specifically, for those values of $\ b\ $ we have
\begin{align}
E\big[e^{-(ax^1-c)}\big]&=\frac{e^{c-aj}-e^{c-ai}}{a(j-i)}\\
E\big[e^{-(ax^2-c)}\big]&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\,\big(\text{erf}(i\sqrt{a})-\text{erf}(j\sqrt{a})\big)}{2\sqrt{a}(j-i)}\ .
\end{align}
For other values of $\ b\ $ you can express the integral as a power series, by using the power series expansion $\ e^z=\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\ $:
$$
E\big[e^{-(ax^b-c)}\big]=\Big(\frac{e^c}{j-i}\Big)\Big(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-a)^ni^{bn+1}}{(bn+1)n!}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-a)^nj^{bn+1}}{(bn+1)n!}\Big)\ .
$$

For an arbitrary function $\ f\ $ it's not possible to give any simpler expression than
$$
\frac{-1}{j-i}\int_i^je^{-f(y)}dy
$$
for $\ E\big[{-}e^{-f(x)}\big]\ $ unless you have much more specific information about the form of $\ f\ $.

The identity $\ E[h(x)]=h\big(E[x]\big)\ $ is only likely to hold if $\ h\ $ is a *linear* function of the form $\ h(x)=cx+d\ $.  For  non-linear functions such as $\ h(x)={-}e^{-(x^b-c)}\ $ it's only going to hold as the result of a very unlikely coincidence.  In fact, for $\ b>1 $ and $\ y>1\ $, $\ {-}e^{-(y^b-c)}\ $ is a [*strictly* concave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function)
function of $\ y\ $, so if $\ i>1\ $ and $\ b>1\ $ then $\ E[h(x)]<h\big(E[x]\big)\ $.

Comment: @Ionza Ieggiera Thank you for the detailed answer. Yes I was not looking at any specific function $f$ as I want it to be as general as can be but for it to be evaluated using elementary functions then perhaps a linear function would be best. Also, the expansion of $E[e^{-(ax^b-c)}]$ using power series seems interesting but does it apply to non-integer values of $b$ or does $b$ need to be an integer?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the power series expansion is the Taylor expansion and it only applies to integer values of $b$ rather than any $b\in \mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: I don't quite follow.  The Taylor expansion $
\ e^z=\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\ $ is valid for all real (and complex) $\ z\ $.  In particular, it holds for $\ z=-ax^b\ $, which gives $\ e^{-ax^b}=\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-ax^b)^n}{n!}\ $.  While this might not be the Taylor expansion of the function $ \varphi(x)=e^{-ax^b}\ $, it's still a perfectly valid identity, and the series is sufficiently well behaved to be integrated term by term, which gives the result I've presented (unless—a very definite possibility—I've made algebraic errors in deriving it).

Comment: Ah yes you're right, somehow I was under the impression that the Taylor series is only valid for natural numbers. This was my mistake.